# Headers already sent error after upgrading wordpress to 4.2.2

Tags: redirect, security, headers

in wordpress version 3.6 and 3.7 everything works great, but with version 4 and above I get:

```
Cannot modify header information - headers already sent
```

the problem line is:

```
header('Location: '. $redirect
```

Is there some security script in the new version?

How can i override it?

Comment: Which file is the "problem line" in?

Comment: the file is in the plugin directory

Comment: But which *file*?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`wp_redirect()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect) function instead of `header()`.

Here is the code example:

```
wp_redirect($redirect);
```

Comment: when i use this same problem but now its not my plugin, its wordpress core: /home/work/public_html/wp-includes/pluggable.php on line 1196

Comment: The problem here is that you have gotten __some text__ or __whitespace__ (spaces, newline) before the opening PHP tag or after the closing PHP tag in your theme's `functions.php` file. There can't be a single character before or after those tags.

Comment: so, why it worked in earlier wordpress versions?

Comment: @DrMosko plenty have changed between 3.7 and 4.0 and many bugs was rectified and new features added. That is why it is important to keep your code up to date with core and php version changes. Your plugin is getting behind and becoming a security risk for those who are using it. Find the bug and fix it

Comment: how do i use wp_redirect() to create onfly page, with get parameters?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a plugin conflict. Rename your plugin folder to disable all plugins and see if the problem still persists. If the proplem is gone reactivate the plugins one by one to see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: thx, but its not a plugin conflict

Answer (score -1):

I dont know whats wrong with the new wordpress version, but somthing has changed, and my plugin hasnt, but i was able to sort it out with ob_start()

Comment: If output buffer fixed it then certainly there was some kind of output before headers were sent to begin with. Using output buffer is great, but if it's only purpose is to fix a bug and not to actually buffer any output then you are using it wrong and would be better served by finding the actual output causing the error.

Comment: You are simply just hiding the error, not resolving/fixing it. This method is not recommended. Buffering should never be your first go-to, but your absolute last. Find the error and **fix** the error, **never** hide it. A hidden error is not debuggable and extremely hard to find later on. Spare yourself that headaches and sleepless nights :-)